# Super slow graphics on fresh install

Tags: graphics, lenovo

Recently I just wiped windows and installed ubuntu on my lenovo yoga 2 pro. THe computer is by far capable of handling text editors, videos, etc. However, everything is super laggy and slow. When I type in the terminal, or even in this current text box it can take up to 10 seconds or so to show changes in what I type. Terminal is super annoying because auto fill and backspaces take even longer and I have to wait in order to keep typing to see if it filled correctly. I also can't watch any videos at all as they stutter drmatically and are impossible to watch. They even stutter if I go to lowest resolution of 140p. With the same computer on windows I could watch HD video that was greater than 1080p with absolutely no problems at all, let alone type a command or text down without lag.

How can I fix this lag in ubuntu?

Things I've tried:
- Lowering screen resolution to 1080 (does nothing different)
- Checked additional Drivers screen (Says there are none)

System Info:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

```
-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:45 memory:b0000000-b03fffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:3000(size=64)

*-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 836MHz
          capacity: 836MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4

lenovo-yoga-2-pro  
    description: Notebook
    product: 20266 (LENOVO_MT_20266_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro)
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro
    width: 64 bits
```

Comment: From most of the research I've done it seems as though this is a problem with the latest LTS build of Ubuntu. I've read many reports of graphics being slow and messed up after upgrading to 14.04.3 - I am going to wipe my computer again and install the old LST 12.04.5 version and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

One answer to solve this is to simply uninstall LTS 14.04.3 and install the old LTS 12.04.5 version of Ubuntu as the problems do not exist on the old version of Ubuntu. I'm not happy with this answer but for now until 14 works as expected or someone posts a better fix I will use 12.